# Why do we construct Lagrangian submanifolds after symplectic reductions

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, submanifold, moment-map

I am learning about Hamilton-Jacobi actions, symplectic reductions and Lagrangian submanifolds and I am trying to understand the relation between these concepts.

I have read that Lagrangian submanifolds are physically interesting as they can be thought of the space of all momenta at fixed coordinate, locally. Moreover, they allow us to recover the variational form of the Hamiltonian mechanics of the system we are dealing with.

As I understand it, symplectic reductions arose from the interest of taking quotients of symplectic manifolds under group actions and the Hamilton-Jacobi group action is the one that makes it possible (via the momentum map $\mu$) as it satisfies several requirements as the dimension and the symplectic structure of the manifold. In particular, the Mardsen-Weinstein-Meyer theorem states that the quotient $\mu^{-1}(0) / G$ is a symplectic manifold. Finally, I have read that this latter quotient captures the original Hamiltonian mechanics.

From this, most of the documents I have read naturally turn to the wish to recover Lagrangian submanifolds from symplectic reductions. For this, they use the level sets of the momentum map.

It is a rough summary and obviously any correction/precision will be appreciated.

My confusion comes from the wish to construct Lagrangian manifolds from symplectic reductions. First, $\mu^{-1}(0) / G$ seems to provide some physical insights on our system and so do Lagrangian submanifolds. So, either they do it in a more interesting/accurate way, or I am missing the point in doing it "twice". Then, the problem is probably that I am a bit short on basic knowledge here but why are we interested in many level sets of $\mu$ and not only the $0$ one? Is it because the variational form of the Hamiltonian mechanics is local?

Comment: It seems that you at least partially answered your own question - reduction and Lagrangian submanifolds provide different physical insights, and therefore you aren't "doing it twice" as you mentioned. A reduction lets you quotient out symmetries, to focus on the "underlying" dynamics. Therefore it seems natural to be interested in the Lagrangian submanifolds of the quotient space.